# Generating a sitemap in Polymer?

Tags: polymer, sitemap

In need of a sitemap for a Polymer built site, which (at first) we thought would be nice to also generate in Polymer. After doing some research however, questions crop up on if a Javascript based implementation would actually be executed or not by Google's bots/crawlers (see: [Generate dynamic sitemap with js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628588/generate-dynamic-sitemap-with-js))?

The counter to this would be Google crawlers can execute Javascript just fine (see: https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html), but we still can't see any solid documentation specific to Polymer and if this would be best practise to do this?

Be great if there could be a definitive answer to this. Thanks

Comment: Did you discover the answer? Did it worked to use polymer to generate the sitemap?

Comment: @FelipeCésar the problem I found is that sitemaps are expected to be received in particular formats (such as .xml). Even if crawlers can parse and execute js, it won't be received with the correct format for it to try (being .xml instead of .html or .js).

Comment: are you going to to use firebase functions or something like this to generate the sitemap?

Comment: No, luckily we had a backend to generate this but it is a real sticking point with frontend frameworks (not to mention metadata for Facebook too, as currently their crawlers don't run JS).